# Sort unanswered questions by amount of views?

Tags: feature-request, questions, search, views

Hello, reading the Additional Badge Ideas thread, I got an idea.

Why don't we make it easier to find those rare posts? For instance, the tumbleweed posts with no votes, low views, and no answers. Right now, all we can get are a ton of unanswered questions to filter through. Why not allow for a new tab on the unanswered questions page labeled "views" where it sorts the unanswered questions by the amount of views?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=votes:0+views:0+answers:0

Comment: wow a lot more 0 view questions than I thought

Comment: yep, and pretty old too!

Comment: Omg doing this search on Super User gives nearly 10% of all the questions like that :O

Comment: This answer appears to be outdated.  [The search page](http://stackoverflow.com/search) says that the `votes` and `views` keywords specify a *minimum*.

Comment: (+1) Cool! I had no idea. ;-)

Comment: @John It is correct, at least for votes and answers. When either of those options is set to 0, it will only search for posts with 0. To get 0 *or more*, you'd have to put `0..` there. The views operator does not have such a restriction and will search for 0 or more (and essentially does nothing at all in this search query). Technically the views operator here doesn't make sense, because it's not possible for a question to have 0 views.

Answer (score 4):

how about adding an ascending version of sort to the existing ones? I've tried it on my askbot project (check it out if you care - there's a link on my profile :).

Basically if you click again on **hot** you will get **cold**, then click again and get the "hot" back? You have the same control (the sort by date of entry tab, but it's action would toggle).

This works ok IMO if the control is rendered as a button with changing text or has a triangle icon inside denoting the sort order, which would flip... just thought of a pure ui-based solution.